# Accidently removed ubuntu boot option, how to add it back

Tags: dual-boot, bios

I have a dual boot, windows 10 and ubuntu 18 computer. I was trying to disable secure boot for ubuntu and I accidently removed it from the boot so now it boots to windows, used to boot to ubuntu by default. How do I add it back?

In the bios setup->boot sequence->add boot option->file name I have:
EFI directory, and under that I have Microsoft, boot, and ubuntu. And under ubuntu I have:
Fxupx64.efi
Grub64.efi
Grub.cfg
Shimx64.efi
Mmx64.efi
Boot64.csv

Not sure if it's one of these or if I need to do anything special

Comment: Try to boot with Shimx64.efi. Then if you'll successfully boot to Ubuntu, just run 'sudo update-grub' (without quotes).

Comment: You can try to run a ubuntu grub repair live session.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/